# Django leaflet canvas

Tags: django, canvas, leaflet, django-leaflet

How to make django-leaflet render with canvas?
I checked on leaflet documentation that it should use `preferCanvas` but there are no manual in django leaflet that shows how to do it, while var map are hidden somewhere... 
Any clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't have access to the [`preferCanvas` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-prefercanvas) or the [`renderer` option of the `L.Map`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-renderer), you can still use the [`renderer` option of **individual** vector layers](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#path-renderer).

Using this in django-less, vanilla javascript would look like:

```
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', { /* map options */ });

var myCanvasRenderer = L.canvas();

var circle = L.circleMarker([0, 0], {
  radius: 30,
  renderer: myCanvasRenderer
}).addTo(map);

var line = L.polyline([[60, 10],[20, 200]], {
  renderer: myCanvasRenderer
}).addTo(map);
```

Make sure that you're creating the `L.Canvas` renderer **once** and reusing it in all your vector layers.

You can confirm this works by using the developer tools of your web browser and noting that there is a `<canvas>` element inside the Leaflet map container, but there is no `<svg>` element to be found:

[image]

You can see this [example live over here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RVYai20Bvp2CHtXa9vs0?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you it works, but I still cant render thousand of point with custom icon smoothly. I guess Canvas is not the solution, Thanks for helping me, I really stuck in this canvas thing for weeks and it turns out it wont help on mass point display...

Comment: Then you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Indeed, I tought that Y will solve my problem, it seems my research about leaflet are not good enough, once again thank you.